# MySql - Insert rows for skipped numbers (interpolation)

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this (simplified):

```
+------+--------+
| tick | value  |
+------+--------+
|    1 |     10 |
|    2 |     20 |
|    5 |     50 |
|    7 |     10 |
|   10 |     85 |
+------+--------+
```

I want to generate **another** table which includes all numbers from `min(tick)` to `max(tick)` as tick values:

```
+------+--------+
| tick | value  |
+------+--------+
|    1 |     10 |           * already exists
|    2 |     20 |           * already exists
|    3 |     30 | = 20 + 10
|    4 |     40 | = 30 + 10
|    5 |     50 | = 40 + 10 * already exists
|    6 |     30 | = 50 - 20
|    7 |     10 | = 30 - 10 * already exists
|    8 |     35 | = 10 + 25
|    9 |     60 | = 35 + 25
|   10 |     85 | = 60 + 25 * already exists
+------+--------+
```

To be clear,

1. I have **non-consecutive** tick values and want to insert missing ticks.
2. I want to do this to **another** table, so original table won't be modified.
3. `value`s of missing `tick`s increases/decreases as **equal steps** from previous existing tick to next existing tick. As a psudo-formula:
   `increment = (next_value - current_value) / (next_tick - current_tick)`

**How to manage this?**

Comment: What's your environment? A pure SQL solution might be much more work than one involving another layer.

Comment: I know, but I have to do this using SQL preferably. I am using Java, but this will be second plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stored procedure will do what you want, populating the table `allticks`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `tickster`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE oldticks INT DEFAULT 0; -- initial ticks here
    DECLARE oldvalue INT DEFAULT 0; -- initial value here
    DECLARE newticks INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE newvalue INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE t INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE v INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE delta INT DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE existing CURSOR FOR SELECT ticks,value FROM ticks ORDER BY ticks;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished=1;

    OPEN existing;

    nexttick: LOOP
        -- Get next value or break
        FETCH existing INTO newticks,newvalue;
        IF finished>0 THEN
            LEAVE nexttick;
        END IF;

        -- initialize a loop to cover the inexistant ticks
        SET t=oldticks+1;
        SET v=oldvalue;
        SET delta=(newvalue-oldvalue)/(newticks-oldticks);

        -- run the loop
        nextstep: LOOP
            IF t>=newticks THEN
                LEAVE nextstep;
            END IF;
            -- calculate new interpolated value and write it to the table
            SET v=v+delta;
            INSERT INTO allticks SET ticks=t, value=v;
            SET t=t+1;
        END LOOP;

        -- write the existing value to the table
        INSERT INTO allticks SET ticks=newticks, value=newvalue;

        -- make new dataset the old dataset
        SET oldticks=newticks;
        SET oldvalue=newvalue;

    END LOOP;
END
```

Add the initial ticks and values where indicated, they are needed, if there is no row with ticks=1

Comment: Very thanks. Seems working. I am trying to understand now :) I will adapt this to original problem.

Comment: Let me know, if you run into trouble

Comment: Only problem is name of the `ticks` table can be change from call to call. It is possible to pass the name as parameter: `tickster('ticks_table_1')`?

Comment: This is not easily possible with MySQL, as metadata (table names) and data (field content) cannot be intermixed. There are ugly hacks around this, but nothing straightforward. On first guess, my recommendation would be to create the stored procedure on demand and drop it after use. If you can make sure, that this is run only non-concurrent you could also make the stored proc reference a view instead of a table and then `CREATE VIEW ticksview SELECT * FROM ${tickstable};` before calling tickster.

Comment: Creating a view seems appropriate for me. What about the performance of using this option, if my `${tickstable}` becomes too large?

Comment: **Reading** from the trivial view instead of the table creates only a negliable performance penalty: I am sure, that **writing** the new table creates at least one order of magnitude more load. The view is definitly not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I created a view using prepared statements, then execute the procedure to populate allticks table and dropped the view. BTW, MySql complained about the syntax error until adding `AS`: `CREATE VIEW ticksview AS SELECT * FROM ${tickstable};`

Comment: Having this same table but with a foreign_id how would you modify the procedure to group by foreign_id

Comment: @acrogenesis I do not fully understand: What does the `foreign_id` do and why would I want to group on it?

Comment: @EugenRieck probably group isn't the correct term. `foreign_id` is an id I get from an API. I get the data but if a "tick" is missing I want to fill in the missing information. The difference for me is I have the `foreign_id` and the ticks correspond to it. So I can have five "1" tick each corresponding to five `foreign_id`s. I wan to fill in the ticks with the values corresponding to each `foreign_id`

Comment: @acrogenesis AHA! If the performance allows it, I would treat it as "n seperate tables" by  filtering for the `foreign_id` in the `existing` cursor and adding it in the `INSERT`, then run  it for every distinct value of `foreign_id`

Answer (score 0):

First you create a Number table

```
Create Table ALL_NUMBERS (
   N Integer
)

Alter table ALL_NUMBERS add primary key (n);
```

Then fill the number table from 1 to a large number, like 1 Million

Then Left Join your data table with this number table and fill the gaps..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is good approach to join with a complete tick set. What about the filling gaps, how such a query does this? BTW, it is enough to have ticks from `min(tick)` to `max(tick)` (1 to 10 in my sample).

Comment: I will write up the query later tonight. I do not have a database handy. If you need a tip, use something like a temp variable and keep checking where your tick has a gap.